# Java Messenger : save message archives on the computer

Tags: java, xml, sqlite, archive, messenger

I am doing a Java Messenger for people to chat and I an looking for a way to record the message archives on the user's computer.

I have 2 possibilities in my mind :

- To Save the conversations in XML files that I store in my documents folder.
- To use SQlite, but the problem is that I don't know how it is possible to integrate it to my setup package and I don't know if it is very useful.

What would be the best solution for you ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using [JavaDb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html), which comes for free with Java 6 (and later versions)

Before you make a choice, you should think about questions such as:

1. presumably you want this transparent to the user (i.e. no admin involved)
2. is performance an issue ?
3. what happens if the storage schema needs migration
4. do you need transactionality (unlikely, I suspect)

etc. It's quite possible that even a simple text file would suffice. Perhaps your best bet is to choose a simple solution (e.g. a text file) and implement that, and see how far it takes you. However, provide a suitable persistence level abstraction such that you can slot in a different solution in the future with minimal disruption.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
1. Yes transparent to the user.
2. Performance, not too important
3. No migration
4. I don't know what it is :)
Do you think that JavaDb is suitable for me ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the XML files as they are more generic and could be opened outside your messenger with more or less human readable format. I use Pidgin for instant messaging and it saves chat history in XML. Also to read the history from your application you can transform then easily in HTML to display it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JAXB, converting Java objects to/from XML is very easy. You just put a few annotations on your classes, and run them through a JAXB marshaller/unmarshaller. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbay.html

Answer (score 0):

Use google's protocolbuffer or 10gen's bson. they are much smaller and faster.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html

http://bsonspec.org/

One issue is these are in the binary presentation and you might want to make the archive transparent/readable to users